# Why Composer package (from github) is not included in autoload_psr4.php or other autoload_*.php files?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload

I have forked Laravel-Firebird package on github as https://github.com/alex153490/laravel-firebird with aim to solve ignite Firebird with Laravel 6 (previous Laravel-Firebird packages were intended for Laravel 5.x) and I arrived at the problem that I can not load class from my new package [Laravel 6 can not found vendor class from the fast-tuned package that was released for the Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096332/laravel-6-can-not-found-vendor-class-from-the-fast-tuned-package-that-was-releas) . I included `var_dump(get_declared_classes());` in my code and Firebird was not mentioned there, so, the package can not be load, although it proudly sits in the vendor folder along other packages that are loaded succesfully. So, I am trying to discover, why the package is not loaded. `composer require` proceeded without errors, `composer diagnose` is without errors too, I can call `composer dumpautload` without improvements.

Now I am researching the vendoer/composer auto-generated package. installed.json contains:

```
   {
        "name": "alex153490/laravel-firebird",
        "version": "1",
        "version_normalized": "1.0.0.0",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/alex153490/laravel-firebird.git",
            "reference": "master"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "installation-source": "source"
    }
```

but none of the autodloading_....php files contains or mentions Firebird or Firebird-Laravel? Why my package (Firebird-Laravel) is not being included into autoloading_....php? And how to correct that?

Comment: I have this issue as well and had to resort to embedding PSR4 specification into application' composer.json: "psr-4": {
      "MyNamespace\\SubNamespace\\": "vendor/MyPackageNamespace/MyPackageDirectory/lib/" }. In your case it would like something like "psr-4": {"Firebird\\" : "vendor/alex153490/laravel-firebird/src/Firebird"}

Comment: Perhaps this is related to update to composer.json - comparing to existing packages like https://github.com/antonioribeiro/version/blob/master/composer.json or https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/blob/master/composer.json - they have an "extra" section with "component": "package" entry.

Comment: Yes, adding this intry in the project's composer.json and doing `composer dumpautoload` brings Firebird into autoload_psr4.php and the class also can be used in the Laravel project files, that is fine. The strange thing is that there is noth mention of the imported classes in the output from `var_dump(get_declared_classes());`, that is strange, but that does not prevent me from proceed with development. I will definitely check the extra sections and let know wheter this can be formatted as the full answer.

Comment: I'll add a link to my question regarding this issue so they can be connected: [Composer - Private package not getting into autoloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208991/composer-private-package-not-getting-into-autoloader)